# How to center header text on an awkward createStackNavigator screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to center the text in my header for my react native app, but I can't center it on this one screen that is written awkwardly. For the normal screens, I have this:

```
const ReferralStack = createStackNavigator({
  Referrals: ReferralScreen,
  otherstuff: stuff,
},
{
  headerMode: headerMode,
  headerBackTitleVisible: false,
  headerLayoutPreset: 'center',
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Referrals',
      headerTransparent: true,
      headerTitleStyle: headerLabelStyle,
    headerStyle: headerStyle,
  }
});
```

This centers the header for the referral screen. The line of code that is centering the text is the **headerLayoutPreset: 'center'**. When applied to this other stack it does not work:

```
const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen,
    headerMode: headerMode,
    headerBackTitleVisible: true,
    mode: 'modal',
  },
  EditEmail: {
    screen: EditEmailScreen,
    headerMode: . . .
    etc...
  }
});

const MoreStack = createStackNavigator({
  More: {
    screen: MoreScreen,
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: headerMode,
    headerBackTitleVisible: false,
    headerLayout: 'center',
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Menu',
        headerTransparent: true,
        headerTitleStyle: headerLabelStyle,
        headerStyle: headerStyle,
    }
  },
  SettingsStack
});
```

This screen is set up completely differently than the previous screen. The **headerLayout: 'center'** code doesn't do anything as far as I can tell.

How can I center the header text for this MoreStack screen?